# What is the purpose of declaring all numbers your code is using in constants and then calling them everywhere in the code? This is in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, numbers, constants

I work at a SaaS company where before I came on, 99% of the code was outsourced so I don't have them to ask. The codebase I'm working on has a huge list of consts like this:

```
const NUMBER = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3,
  .....
  forty: 40
}
```

This NUMBER const is used almost everywhere. For example, if there was a line of code accessing index 1 of an array, the code would be :

```
value = array[NUMBER.one];
```

These consts used to be everywhere, but I have been slowly phasing it out. These consts are used in HTML response status numbers like 200, 300, and even in default values for math calculations. I'm wondering if there is a good use for this coding practice that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: Constants are fine but constants whose values are the same as their names are pointless. It's like somebody took bad notes in a freshman CS class. Generally you want things like MAX_FILE_SIZE or READ_TIMEOUT so the constant *value* can change (in one place) and the meaning is clear in context.

Comment: @Pointy. That makes sense. The code is riddled with a large amount of other constants that have the same value as thier name. The code I deal with is a huge mess as it is.